# How to handle some urls in nginx both via http and https and redirect all the rest to https

Tags: nginx, https

For now I have this type of solution:

```
# HTTP server setup
server {
    server_name dev.server.com ;
    listen 80;
    set root /usr/local/www/me ;

    # So here comes the tricky part to allow handling some urls
    # both via http / https:

    set $allow_http 'no' ;

    if ($uri ~* "^\/(internal|export)\/") {
        set $allow_http 'yes' ;
    }

    if ($request_uri = '/some/?tricky=url') {
        set $allow_http 'yes' ;
    }

    if ($allow_http = 'no') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri ;
    }

    include /home/me/main.conf ;
}

# HTTPS server setup
server {
    server_name dev.server.com ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    set root /usr/local/www/me ;

    include /home/me/main.conf ;
}
```

It works like this.

But maybe there is a better way accomplish the same result without using all this `if`s?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if it is "better" perce, but you can define a default location as:

```
# Default redirect to SSL server
location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and instead of using Ifs, configure your special cases as locations, like:

```
location ~* /(internal|export)/ {
   echo "Doing internal http stuffs here"
}
```

Having separate locations offers you greater flexibility and looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, but then I will have to duplicate this part `location ~* /(internal|export)/ { ... }` for both http and https server.

Comment: If you need them in both you can just  move them to your main.conf, can't you?